# Combinatorics: Probability of winning a lottery with specifications of number choices

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I have the following question.

> A state lottery is called ”6/49” for the reason that players have to
>   choose six different numbers from the numbers from 1 to 49, inclusive.
>   One wins the first prize if he/she gets all the numbers correct, the
>   second prize if only 5 of the 6 numbers are correct and the third
>   price if only 4 of the 6 numbers are correct. How many times is one
>   more likely to win the second prize than the first?

I know there are C(49,6) ticket possibilities, which is 13,983,816. My question is how do you solve the last question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution

Comment: @AnginaSeng could you elaborate how the hyper-geometric will work here? If the universe/‘denominator’ is 49c6 what would you put in the ‘numerator’ 48c5*1c1? I don’t think I understand how the usage of hyper- geometric would work here and appreciate your direction. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $6$ ways to choose which $5$ of the winning number you have picked,  For each of those choices there are $43$ ways to pick the sixth number on the card, since it can be any of the number that doesn't come up.  This give $6\cdot43=258$.  So, $258$ times more likely, since there's only one way to choose the winning ticket.